# django context processor

Tags: django

I have a bunch of variables that need to be available to the view for all templates. It seems the best choice would be a context processor.

The documentation says:

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It’s just a Python
>   function that takes one argument, an HttpRequest object, and returns a
>   dictionary that gets added to the template context. Each context
>   processor must return a dictionary.

If I need to do more advanced lookups, can I define other functions? Do the functions need to be in a class? I was thinking of creating a file named `context_processors.py` in my app folder.

Answer (score 8):

You can define other functions, and the functions don't need to be in a class.

Typically people put their context processors into a `context_processors.py` like you're thinking of as functions, and then name them all in `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

For example, here's an app that has the `context_processors.py` inside it: [django-seo](https://github.com/glavit/django-seo).